# Вывести все элементы

Tags: php

Я получаю и обрабатываю данные, затем в последствии конвертирую всё в массив примерно вот таким способом:

```
$urljson=file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=5BC0F61DCDAFEDB5E0DB20D0D1280E&steamids=" . implode($arr));

$data = (array)json_decode($urljson)->response->players[0];
```

А выводить, например содержимое блока *profileurl* можно так:

```
echo $data['profileurl'];
```

Но мне это не подходит, мне надо вывести полностью мой **$data** в формате *json*?

Answer (score 1):

var_dump($data) выдаст весь массив с его структурой, если положить его в тег pre он еще и будет легко читаем.

Или используйте json_encode($data) json_decode($data) для кодирования и декодирования json